# Is there a way to return the primary key of inserted record with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Well, the question kinda nails it down.
I'm currently doing something like this:

```
using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
     using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
     {
         Car newCar = new Car();
         newCar.name = "Jeep";

         session.Save(newCar);
         transaction.Commit();    
     }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Fluent NHibernate. Please change the question title.

Comment: It's what I'm using.  How does this have nothing to do with it?

Comment: What you are using in the above code in NHibernate, and Fluent NHibernate is just a way to map your entities, which NHibernate is oblivious too. You could use xml or attributes too and above code would still be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return newCar.Id;
```

After you've committed your transaction of course.

Comment: Hmmm...that is not being set by the commit according to the debugger.  Is there something I need to set for that member variable in the mapping to enable this behavior?

Comment: @CrypticPrime and you have your breakpoint on the return statement? and primary key is mapped as identity?

Comment: This answer is actually correct.  The problem is that I had the following in the mapping:

            Id(x => x.carID)
                .Column("carID");
                .GeneratedBy.Assigned();   // OFFENDING LINE

Removing the OFFENDING LINE lets NHibernate populate that variable with the newly generated primary key the database auto-increments.
It was legacy code from a prototype and is now removed.